# Apache mod-rewrite .htaccess subdomain redirect issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to get my .htaccess configured properly to setup a subdomain redirect for specific subdomains. I want to redirect (not mask) a subdomain to a specific page and repeat this configuration multiple times.

I'm hosted on a Google Compute Engine currently using Cloud DNS (used to host on Godaddy in which subdomain management was very simple)

```
before:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

after:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sat.theteachertutors.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /private-sat-act-tutoring/$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried the config above but the redirect does not work. The target url is: https://www.theteachertutors.com/private-sat-act-tutoring/
Any guidance/tips would be most appreciated. I've search for other examples but can't get this configuration to work at all, ie: http://sat.theteachertutors.com

Thanks

Comment: Which Apache version 2.2 or 2.4? Have you tried adding the "R" flag in the rewriterule? like this: 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /private-sat-act-tutoring/$1  [R,L]`

Comment: Hi - i tried that as per below but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution, change the rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.theteachertutors.com/private-sat-act-tutoring/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When you are redirecting to another domain/subdomain you have to use the full URL. Also I use `R=301` to mark the redirect as a permanent redirect (by default rules that point to another domain use a 302 redirect).

Comment: Hi @Alberto-martinez.  I made the suggested change but https://sat.theteachertutors.com does not work. Any other thoughts? 
 # BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sat.theteachertutors.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.theteachertutors.com/private-sat-act-
tutoring/$1 [R=301,L]  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  
# END WordPress

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to access the subdomain? Also, is the subdomain pointing to the same location that the www domain? I mean, I supposed that you have previously configured the subdomain to point to the directory in which the .htaccess file is located, which seems to be the root directory of the main domain, is that right?

Comment: Hi @alberto-martinez, When attempting to reach the url I get: This site can’t be reached sat.theteachertutors.com took too long to respond.
Basically I want the subdomain to forward to the page on the site. the .htaccess file is in the root of the main domain. It seems that when accessing the subdomain url (https://sat.theteachertutors.com/) the request doesnt hit the .htaccess file. Could there be additional config required in google cloud dns? Thanks!